# Javascript/jQuery Countdown Timer with Update Capability

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I’ve seen several examples for Javascript/jQuery countdown timers. I have implemented a 15 minute countdown timer based off the example at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp). However, I would like to add an update feature that allows me to add/subtract time to and from the clock. The timer starts at 15 minutes.

In my project the user  will answers  questions. After they answer the question and select submit, a time penalty or bonus is given.  The penalty subtracts 3 seconds from the clock. The bonus adds 2 seconds to it. Below is an example of my code:

```
var mission_timer = 15;

function start_timer(){
        
        countDownDate  = new Date().getTime() + mission_timer * 60 * 1000;
        timer_interval = setInterval(function() {

            var now                   = new Date().getTime();
            var distance              = countDownDate - now;
            var minutes               = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var minutes_number_length = Number(String(minutes).length);
            var seconds               = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
            var seconds_number_length = Number(String(seconds).length);
            
            current_time = document.getElementById("game_timer").innerHTML = "TIME: " + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            update_timer = null;
            time_update  = 0;
            
            if (current_time === "TIME: 00:00") {
                $("#game_timer").css("color", "red");
                clearInterval(timer_interval);
                console.log("Time Expired");
            }else
            if (current_time === "TIME: 01:00") {
                $("#game_timer").css("color", "yellow");
                console.log("One Minute Left");
            }
        
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I attached the code to my original post for review. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The counter works using countDownDate and now. You have to modify the countDownDate variable to add/substract time when user answers the questions.

```
//bonus for correct answer
countDownDate += 2 * 1000;
```

And

```
//penalty for wrong answer
countDownDate -= 3 * 1000;
```

Both of them have to be triggered by the Submit event of the question answered.